# Spring authorization server not redirecting back to frontend app (nextjs) after authentication

Tags: redirect, spring-security, frontend, http-status-code-404, spring-authorization-server

I have a Java Spring backend api with Spring Authorization server running on localhost:8080 and a Nextjs frontend running on localhost:3000. After registering a user, I'm correctly getting redirected to authorization server's login page. I enter the correct username and password and can see in the Spring logs that the user is authenticated:

namePasswordAuthenticationToken, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=4FEB7A8392B22372152176A6F947D0BA], Granted Authorities=[User]]

Now I want to get redirected to my frontend app, where I've set up a page to receive the code from the response and make another call to retrieve the token. Instead, I get 404 (it says that there is no specific /error page, but does not say what the error is).

Here is my Spring authorization config:

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }
 

    @Bean 
        public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
            RegisteredClient linguaClient = RegisteredClient.withId("lingua-client.frontend")
                    .clientId("lingua-client")
                    .clientSecret("secret")
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .redirectUri("http://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/lingua-client")
                    .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:3000")
                    .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                    .scope("user.read")
                    .scope("user.write")
                    .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                    .build();
    
            return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(linguaClient);
        }
```

And this is where I construct the call client side:

```
  const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
    const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/lingua-client');
    const response_type = 'code';
    const scope = encodeURIComponent('user.read user.write');
    const authServerUrl = process.env.AUTH_SERVER;

    const authUrl = `${authServerUrl}/authorize?response_type=${response_type}&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope};
```

I have a page at http://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/lingua-client that's listening for the call but never getting there.

I tried different redirect urls because I'm not sure if it needs to follow a specific format. I also tried directly accessing the url from the browser but still got a 404.

UPDATE: I was able to get redirected with authorization code by adding the following security chain filter:

```
@Bean 
@Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
            // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
            // authorization endpoint
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                    new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                )
            )
        return http.build();
    }
```

Now I get the authorization code, but after making call to token endpoint, I get invalid_client.

Comment: Please enable trace logging to see additional details with `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`. Having said that, I'd recommend using an officially supported OpenID Connect library for your client. You are missing several parameters including PKCE.

Comment: I was able to get the authorization code by adding another security chain config so now I am working on getting the token itself. So you're saying I should use a library for that, like node openid-client? Is PKCE necessary if I have a single trusted client and I'm using client_id and client_secret? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using a JavaScript/SPA application as the client (without proxying requests through a backend-for-frontend) you cannot have a trusted client (called "confidential client"), it is considered a "public client" because you cannot securely provide a client secret. So in that case, PKCE is 100% necessary. It is also recommended even in the case of a confidential client, but is not required in that case. Spring Authorization Server enforces the PKCE requirement for public clients.

Comment: I have a node server in my frontend app which I'm using to make the call that  includes client secret. If it's not too complicated, I can add PKCE since it's recommended but right now my priority is figuring out how to get basic oauth2 flow working. I'm currently getting invalid_client after calling token endpoint with the code I received.

Comment: Enable trace logging and share the logs, we can see what is going wrong causing you to get an invalid_client error.

Comment: I did not see any clues in the trace logs but just tried encoding the client secret with password encoder in RegisteredClient and got the token successfully. Appreciate your time @SteveRiesenberg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the initial problem of not getting redirected back to my redirectUri with authorization code by adding the following securityfilterchain:

```
@Bean 
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
            // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
            // authorization endpoint
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                    new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                )
            )
            // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }
```

Once I got the code and used it to make a call to token endpoint, I was getting invalid_client error. I resolved that by encoding the password in Registered client:

```
    @Bean 
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient linguaClient = RegisteredClient.withId("lingua-client")
                .clientId("lingua-client")
                .clientSecret(encoder().encode("secret"))
         ...
```